# "from little things, big things grow" en français ?

Tags: traduction, anglais, expressions

Comment exprimer "from little things, big things grow" en français ?

Je recherche une expression qui marque l'accumulation d'expérience.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

L'expression qui marque le mieux l'accumulation d'expérience en français est :

> C'est en forgeant qu'on devient forgeron.

Mais la traduction de cette expression en anglais serait :

> Practice makes perfect.

Ce qui ne veut pas exactement dire la même chose.

D'autres expressions peuvent correspondre ; même si elles ne sont pas tout à fait similaires, elles marquent l'accumulation. Je pense à

> Les petits ruisseaux font les grandes rivières.
>
> Il n'y a pas de petites économies.
>
> Qui sème le vent, récolte la tempête.

Answer (score 6):

*Petit à petit, l'oiseau fait son nid.* Mais cette expression n'est pas limitée à l'expérience.